# What is recommendation/reference draft copy?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, terminology

I am applying for a PhD program and reached out for a recommendation to a professor under who I had done my master’s thesis. He told me to:

> send a draft copy as per the requirement

What does that mean? Am I to write my own recommendation and how?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Do you have any ideas to what requirement he might be referring? (Please [edit] your question to clarify.)

Comment: No idea about requirements, couldn't find anything, bit wary of asking him also.

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly common, though not universal, that a professor will ask the student to write a draft of a recommendation letter. More generally, he is asking what you would like him to stress in the letter. This frees him from the need to investigate the requirements of the individual university and will refresh his memory about what you did together.

So, yes, provide a draft. Say what you have done and what you think your future potential is. Don't make it too obvious that you are writing about yourself, of course. But make it positive.